# Windows Service Not Working

Tags: c#, service

I'm new to windows service and I'm facing a problem I need to call a function on my services on start method but its not working. When I'm starts the service the following error occures

> "The MIM service on local Computer started and then stopped.Some
>   service stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or
>   programs"

and my current code is given below

```
public CHK()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Message("ChkUser", "Service Start", "");
    CheckUser();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    Logger.Message("MChkUser", "Service Stop", "");
}
public void CheckUser()
{
   //actions
}
```

and If I didnt call the CheckUser() method then the service works without any problem. What will be the reason behind this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the reason is that your `CheckUser()` method throws an uncaught exception ...

To see what the exception is try simply putting the call to the method inside a try-catch block :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Message("ChkUser", "Service Start", "");
    try {
    CheckUser();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      Logger.Message("ChkUser", e.Message, "");
    }
}
```